# Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then power set of $A$ is a subset of power set of $B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you prove this?

$A \subseteq B \rightarrow P(A) \subseteq P(B)$

I said, if I neglect the elements exclusive to $B$ and create a power set of $B$, we get power set of $A$. Thus, the power set of $B$ contains the power set of $A$.

Is this a valid way to prove this statement? I feel like I am missing some of the rigorous mathematics in my proof.

Comment: This is an immediate result of the definition of the power set of B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote $P(X)$ the power set of the set $X$: its elements are the subsets of $X$.

Suppose $A\subset B$.

An element $S\in P(A)$ is a subset of $A$, and $S\subset A\subset B$ shows that $S$ is also a subset of $B$. Thus $S\in P(B)$.

Since every element of $P(A)$ is also an element of $P(B)$ we conclude that $P(A)\subset P(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be an element of the power set of $A$, i.e., $X\subseteq A$.Then $X\subseteq B$ because $A\subseteq B$, i.e., $X$ belongs to the power set of $B$.